# Any Risk To Share Zone -file of a Website in Internet?

Tags: dns, privacy

I have problem with DNS settings and I cannot find any other way than share my settings.

The Zone -file contains SOA record, A records, CNAME records, MX records and NS records.

Is there any danger to share them unmodified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of DNS is to make this information to other computers, so I can't think of anything that you wouldn't want to make public.

You can see what can already be found out about your domain using [this tool](http://www.pageutils.com/dns-query-tool.php).